# Prolog --> operator-operator expected

Tags: prolog, dcg

I've received some code as an example for a task at uni. I'm trying to get their example to run so I can then look at a working example to make the similar stuff that I need to. I fixed most of the errors in there (they had "-- >" instead of "-->") but it still gives me an error message.

```
example.pl:4:0: Syntax error: Operator expected
% example.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 240 bytes
true.

expr --> num.
expr --> num, "+", expr.
expr --> num, "-", expr.
num --> [D] { D >= "0", "9" >= D}.
```

I've never used anything like the last line before, so I don't know what the error is. I googled stuff about the "-->" operator, because I also haven't used that before so thought there could be a link, but I didn't turn up anything useful about it.
I'm using swi-prolog.

Comment: --> is used to seperate the head from the body in DCG clauses, {code} basically includes code in prolog in the DCG clause http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.11%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/DCG.html%27%29%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma in the last clause: `[D], ...`